Why is the argument `nelp` in POSIX's `lfind` function (search.h) not `const`?
POSIX Issue 7, 2018 defines the prototype of function lfind in search.h as:
void *lfind(const void *, const void *, size_t *,
            size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));

Or, more clearly from the LSEARCH(3P) man page:
void *lfind(const void *key, const void *base, size_t *nelp,
            size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

nelp is a size_t* and not a const size_t *. This makes sense for lsearch, which can insert an item and thus must update *nelp, but I don't see the utility for lfind:

The integer to which nelp points shall beincremented if the entry is added to the table.


The lfind() function shall be equivalent to lsearch(), except that if the entry is not found, it is not added to the table.  Instead, a null pointer is returned.

Is this a missing qualifier, or is there a situation in which *nelp has to be modified in lfind?
Edit: some comments mention that it's for consistency; and indeed that would explain why lfind does not use size_t nelp (so that both receive a pointer), but it does not explain why the const is in base (const void *base vs. void *base) but not in nelp (size_t *nelp in both cases); the const in nelp would not affect users passing pointers.

Per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lfind.html I find it interesting that lfind() has a const void *base as an argument, but lsearch() has void *base.  It does seem strange that the const is dropped for void *base but not size_t *nelp

The answer will be "Historical Reasons", aka "precedent".  The functions came from SVID (System V Interface Definition) Version 1 according to the POSIX definition. When I look at an SVR4 Programmer's Manual published in 1989, the lfind() and lsearch() functions are defined with non-const size_t *nelp.  I expect POSIX simply took the precedent to avoid invalidating existing implementations.  If you were designed the interface, you'd not pass a pointer to lfind() for the size — you'd simply pass the size.  The interface makes it easier to switch between lfind() and lsearch().

See the POSIX definition of the lfind() function (the page also defines lsearch()).  The definition there includes the argument names.

@Kevin But they don't hace the same prototype - it's size_t *nelp without const for both, but void *base has const for lfind() while lsearch() doesn't have const.  If identical arguments is the reason, you could say it was poorly implemented...

I added a mention to the fact that the functions do differ in const-ness for the base argument but not for the nelp argument. I tend to prefer believing this was a mistake, that the const was simply forgotten back then...
